# Exception in junit cases implementation for Spring batch

Tags: spring, exception, junit, spring-batch

I am writing junit testcase for spring batch application.Code is given below

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { AppTest.BatchTestConfig.class })
public class AppTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void demo() throws Exception {
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();

        Assert.assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getStatus());
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    static class BatchTestConfig {

        @Bean
        JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils() {
            return new JobLauncherTestUtils();
        }

    }
}
```

but the same is giving exception given below:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncherTestUtils': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setJob' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Please suggest

Comment: What `Job` are you expecting to execute?

Comment: Hi..i have just one job in my spring batch application.But I dont know How to execute it in Junit.Can u plz tell me

Answer (score 2):

This line:

`@SpringBootTest(classes = { AppTest.BatchTestConfig.class })`

loads your test configuration only, but that configuration doesn't contain a `Job` to test.  You need to include the configuration with your job in the `classes` array, for example:

`@SpringBootTest(classes = { AppTest.BatchTestConfig.class, MyJobConfig.class })`

Comment: hi..thanks for the reply.I am new in spring batch.Can u plz tell me how and where to add job configurations.Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure @Programming_Geek, I updated my answer.  Let me know if it doesn't make sense.